# Google Maps API V2 addMarker and OnCameraChangeListener

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-maps-android-api-2

**Scenario**

- Initial user position is read and a marker is added + camera position is set to that location.
- Each time the user drags/zooms the camera I need to call a web service and pass the rectangle coordinates of the map. This web service returns a list of locations to be displayed as markers which are within the map's bounds.

So basically I am doing something like:

**onCreate**

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        // Make a web call for the locations
        myTask = new MyTask();
        myTask.execute();
}
```

On task **onPostExecute** for each item returned from the web service I make:

```
mMap.addMarker(
    new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(myPoint.getLatitude(), myPoint.getLongitude())
    )
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_pushpin))
);
```

**The expected behavior:**: each time the user scrolls or zooms, the camera position changes and the async task gets called again to get a fresh batch of active coordinates

**The actual behavior**: infinite loop between `onPostExecute` and `OnCameraChangeListener`.

From what it seems to me, but maybe I am wrong, the `addMarker` triggers a camera change event ? How can I make the expected behavior described above ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what it seems to me, but maybe I am wrong, the addMarker triggers a camera change event ?

No, it doesn't. You may want to add full code for other to try to solve this puzzle.

> The expected behavior:: each time the user scrolls or zooms, the camera position changes and the async task gets called again to get a fresh batch of active coordinates

Why would you want to fetch the same data every time user changes camera position?

Some considerations to improve user experience:

- Getting all data only once and storing them into SQLite DB. Of course if data changes, you need to sync them and that would probably require changing webservice a bit. Do not download everything on simple user interface change.
- Keeping webservice communication outside `Activity` context for memoryleak-less solution. If you have your `MyTask` as an inner class inside `Activity`, this will keep destroyed `Activity` in memory until task finishes.
- Only adding markers in visible region and not removing them if they were already added. Number of markers will keep growing, but it is better than calling `clear()` every time user moves the map. Like CommonsWare correctly suggests: less IPC is better. For this I can suggest [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/). Even if you don't use marker clustering, it has an option to add markers dynamically, so you don't need to write this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the fact that addMarker doesn't trigger camera update. I looked in my code a bit more and saw the problem (a bad activity restart :) )  The thing with the markers is that they are dynamic most of the time and that's why I am reading them all again.

Comment: @Alin How often is most of the time? Do markers represent people? It's still not good to use `onCameraChange` to trigger. User doesn't have to interact for a longer time or can swipe like crazy to see what markers are there on Antarctica. Getting data updates in X minutes / hours / days is probably much better. Of course polling will never beat push.

Comment: the projects specifications are: get markers when the user swipes/zooms or otherwise every 30 seconds. The markers are cars. The thing is, the web service only returns data for the visible coordinates, so if I drag a bit off, i need to update the rest of the markers+ display new markers. As I see it, the only way would be to get the web service called every time. The markers are around 10-15 I believe. The app is very specific and will be used only in certain cities, so no need for the user to zoom out/swipe too much.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the expected behavior described above ?

First, only invoke `MyTask` if the data is different than the previous task. If there is no actual camera change, then the coordinates should be the same as your last task, and you don't need to hit the server again.

Second, only add markers that are not already on the map (and don't remove markers that were already removed, for that matter). Even if there are subtle camera changes that the previous step does not address, those changes are unlikely to result in a change in the lineup of markers. I presume that your current logic is to blow away all markers and reload them all, and that's not especially efficient, regardless of this camera-change behavior. Pretty much any call on `GoogleMap` involves IPC, so you want to have as few of those as possible.